# What changed in nornir 3.30 from ver.2.8.3 I can't file certain files like Nornirinit

Tags: python

cannot import name 'netmiko_send_command' this works in 2.8.3 but not Nornir 3.30 ?

```
from nornir import Initnornir
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Initnornir' from 'nornir'
> (C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\nornir_*init*_.py) PS
> C:\Python\Python39>

---

```py
from nornir import init_nornir

nr = ("config.yml")

from nornir.plugins.tasks import netmiko_send_command
from nornir.plugins.functions import print_result

result = nr.run(netmiko_send_command, command_string="sh ip int brief")

print_result(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go and look in cases like this for the upgrade logs / change logs in the versions since its here a major version change from 2 to 3 there are a lot of changes.

In your case its there: [Upgrade Logs](https://nornir.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/upgrading/2_to_3.html)

They write:

> **InitNornir**
> Passing callables as inventory plugin and transform functions is no longer supported
> configure_logging has been removed (it used to indicate it was to be deprecated)